# not able to find hive table directory using hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I hit a hard block when using hive table. when using hive table. 
when using `DESCRIBE FORMATTED tbl_name`, I can see the location: hdfs path. when running query, there are some records return. when I run create table new_table as select * from tbl_name. the table can created, but not data. 
where check hdfs using hdfs dfs -ls /table directory, it return "no such file or directory".

anybody has any idea about this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if your previous table has data or not ?

Comment: Side note: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` is way more readable that `DESCRIBE`...

Answer (score 0):

You can see  $HIVE_HOME/conf directory there is the hive-default.xml and/or hive-site.xml which has the `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property.

for example if it is `/usr/hive/warehouse`.

```
hadoop fs -ls -R /usr/hive/warehouse/*
```

still if you are not able to find then

```
hadoop fs -ls -R | grep hive or your table name.
```

then you could able to see that.

Comment: were you able to try? was it useful?

Comment: Hi Ram, I tried, but it doesn't work. I am still not able to see the file.

Comment: ***when using DESCRIBE FORMATTED tbl_name, I can see the location: hdfs path.***. Can you print this path? I need some more inputs from you.  you have to mention more details in your question. I think these details are not enough.

Comment: am seeing this hdfs://docker-hive-master_namenode_1:8020/user/hive/warehouse/pokes.  then i logged on to namenode and tried to look for user folder.. i dont see any